# Neo4j unable to establish connection NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, neo4j

I'm trying to connect to Neo4J cloud API using Node.

I've added all the necessary details to connect,

When I tried to execute with query, I'm getting this error

> Neo4jError: Failed to connect to server. Please ensure that your
>   database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have
>   compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note
>   that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0. Caused
>   by: Failed to establish connection in 30000ms

```
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')
const driver = neo4j.driver(URL, neo4j.auth.basic('User', 'Pass'),
  {
    encrypted: 'ENCRYPTION_OFF',
    trust: 'TRUST_ALL_CERTIFICATES'
  })
const session = driver.session();
const query = ` MATCH (ee:PhoneNo) RETURN ee LIMIT 5`

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  session
    .run(query)
    .then(res => {
      res.records.forEach(record => {
        console.log(record);
      })
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    })
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the `URL`?
eg: if you are running localhost, the browser is available on `http://localhost:7474/`? so your URL should be `bolt://localhost`

talking about that, maybe try to use an OGM `neo4j-node-ogm` can help you as well